# How to clear warnings for undefined properties in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php for conditional navigation display?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, navigation

I wrote a function that changes the primary navigation based on whether or not the user is logged in and based on their membership status if they are. Here is the function:

```
function custm_navigation_args($args) {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) { 
        $memid = get_current_user_id();
        if ($memid != 0) {
            global $wpdb;
            $mems = $wpdb->get_results("select statement that grabs all users with specific membership ids");

            $memb_group = array();
            ksort($memb_group, SORT_NUMERIC);

            if (!empty($mems)) {
                foreach ($mems as $key => $item) {
                    $memb_meta = get_object_vars($item);
                    foreach ($memb_meta as $meta_in => $membdetails) {
                        $memb_group[$item->user_id]['memship'] = $memb_meta['memberships'];
                    }
                }

                $membprof = '';

                foreach($memb_group as $mmm) {
                    $membprof .= $mmm['memship'];
                    if (!isset( $args['theme_location']) || $args['theme_location'] == "") {
                       $args['theme_location'] = 'primary-menu';
                    }
                    if ($membprof == '2017' || $membprof == '2048') {
                        $args['menu'] = 36;
                    } else if ($membprof == '2031' || $membprof == '2050') {
                        $args['menu'] = 38;
                    } else if ($membprof == '44' || $membprof == '1557' || $membprof == '1936') {
                        $args['menu'] = 2;
                    } else if ($membprof == '2326' || $membprof == '536') {
                        $args['menu'] = 41;
                    } else if ($membprof == '2364' || $membprof == '2371') {
                        $args['menu'] = 42;
                    }                    
                }
            } else {
                $args['menu'] = 37; //Logged Out Menu
            }
        }
        return $args;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'custm_navigation_args' );
```

The function works, but every time a user logs in, the error log updates with the following warnings:

- PHP Warning:  Undefined property:
  stdClass::$menu in ./wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 125
- PHP Warning:  Undefined property:
  stdClass::$theme_location in ./wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on
  line 129
- PHP Warning:  Undefined property:
  stdClass::$theme_location in ./wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on
  line 134
- PHP Warning:  Undefined property:
  stdClass::$container in ./wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line
  175
- PHP Warning:  Undefined property:
  stdClass::$depth in ./wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 228
- PHP Warning:  Undefined property:
  stdClass::$menu_class in ./wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line
  247

I verified with wp_registered_nav_menus that the theme location name is correct. I can remove the IF statement defining the theme_location, but I still get the same result in the error log. What is also interesting is the error log updates exactly 3 times with all of the same warnings. I am using the Divi theme.

How can I clean up these warnings and keep the function working as it is intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just able to get back to this and solved the issue myself. If you are seeing any of the same issues in the error_log as I documented here, this is what I did to fix my own code, and it completely cleared up the warnings/errors in the log:

```
function custm_navigation_args($args) {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) { 
        $memid = get_current_user_id();
        if ($memid != 0) {
            global $wpdb;
            $mems = $wpdb->get_results("select statement that grabs all users with specific membership ids");

            $memb_group = array();
            ksort($memb_group, SORT_NUMERIC);

        if (!empty($mems)) {
            foreach ($mems as $key => $item) {
                $memb_meta = get_object_vars($item);
                foreach ($memb_meta as $meta_in => $membdetails) {
                    $memb_group[$item->user_id]['memship'] = $memb_meta['memberships'];
                }
            }

            $membprof = '';

            foreach($memb_group as $mmm) {
                $membprof .= $mmm['memship'];
                 //Removed - Not Needed
                //if (!isset( $args['theme_location']) || $args['theme_location'] == "") {
                   //$args['theme_location'] = 'primary-menu';
                //}
                if ($membprof == '2017' || $membprof == '2048') {
                    $args['menu'] = 36;
                } else if ($membprof == '2031' || $membprof == '2050') {
                    $args['menu'] = 38;
                } else if ($membprof == '44' || $membprof == '1557' || $membprof == '1936') {
                    $args['menu'] = 2;
                } else if ($membprof == '2326' || $membprof == '536') {
                    $args['menu'] = 41;
                } else if ($membprof == '2364' || $membprof == '2371') {
                    $args['menu'] = 42;
                }                    
            }
        //} else { //MOVED
            //$args['menu'] = 37; //Logged Out Menu
        }
    //return $args; //MOVED
    } else {
        $args['menu'] = 37; //Logged Out Menu
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'custm_navigation_args' );
```